# I want to use big integer in my android app but when ever i apply operators i get error?

Tags: java, android, biginteger

I want to calculate factorial my code at present is this:

```
else if(btn.getText().equals("x!"))
    {
        double LeftVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);
        double result = Double.NaN;
        if(currentInputLen > 0 && LeftVal >0)
        {
            result = Factorial(LeftVal);
        }

        resultText.setText(result+"");
    }
```

code to calculate factorial is this:

```
private double Factorial(double input)
{
    double output=input;
    for(int i=(int) (input-1);i>0;i--)
    {
        output*=i;
    }

    return output;
}
```

I imported java.math.*; and changed my code to this:

```
else if(btn.getText().equals("x!"))
    {
        BigInteger LeftVal = BigInteger(currentInput);
        BigInteger result = 0;
        if(currentInputLen > 0 && LeftVal >0)
        {
            result = Factorial(LeftVal);
        }

        resultText.setText(result+"");
    }
```

and factorial method to this

```
private BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger input)
{
    BIgInteger output=input;
    for(int i=(int) (input-1);i>0;i--)
    {
        output*=i;
    }

    return output;
}
```

I saw on android developer site that BigInteger(string)  will convert that string to big integer but that does not work and shows error also there were errors on using regular mathematical errors.

The reason i want to use big integer is because if i calculate 12! using double it shows answer in scientific form with e raised to power something i want exact answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'long' type instead?

Comment: the issue is that 12! gives me 4.790016E8 but i want 479001600. Also i can't figure out how to use big integer

Comment: but 4.790016E8 is == 479001600.  4.790016E8 is a different notation for  4.790016 x 10^8

Comment: long wont give accurate answers for say 100!

Comment: i want to say it looses precision it was okay for 12! but for 100! results would change in exponential notation for 100 factorial it would be 9.332621544394418e157 so it looses precision.

Comment: 100! is an absolutely massive number. Too big for any programming language to naturally store. For that number, you're going to have to stick with exponential notation.

Comment: Is there any way i can use big integer because it provides arbitrary precision.People solve question using java big integer on online judges. I just do not how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your factorial method using BigInteger you could use:

```
private BigInteger factorial(BigInteger input) {
    BigInteger output = input;
    for (BigInteger i = input.subtract(BigInteger.ONE); i.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0; i = i.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        output = output.multiply(i);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: How do i convert "double LeftVal = Double.parseDouble(currentInput);"
and "double result = Double.NaN;" to big integer because they would be input to function and hold its output respectively?

Comment: `BigInteger leftVal = new BigInteger(currentInput);` for the input and I think you will have to find an alternative to Double.NaN when using BigInteger, such as throwing an exception for incorrect input.

Comment: When i wrote BigInteger leftVal = BigInteger(currentInput); it did not work but when i wrote BigInteger leftVal = new BigInteger(currentInput); it worked will you please explain why that happened

Comment: `BigInteger` is a class and `BigInteger(String val)` is a constructor for the class. To call the constructor you must use the `new` keyword.

Comment: Thanx mate. All you guys on stack overflow are really helpful